# How to set up hit-test AR in A-Frame?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, hittest

How can one do AR hit-test (markerless) scene in A-Frame? I’ve tried 6 or 7 examples and none of them work.

I need this to work on iPhone and I’m using [Variant Launch](https://launch.variant3d.com/).  They have a very nice example using ThreeJS ([source](https://github.com/Variant3d/launch-examples/tree/main/threejs)) which works extremely smoothly – see QR code attached. I would like to achieve the same kind of experience using A-Frame. (edited)

[image: threejs ar example]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and made a demo here with a new component "ar-hit-test-simple" (to distinguish from the [default A-Frame `ar-hit-test` component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.5.0/components/ar-hit-test.html))

preview: https://launch-aframe-hit-test-simple.glitch.me/

Tapping to "select" will reposition the rover model.

code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/launch-aframe-hit-test-simple

The new component was largely based on this repo:
https://github.com/stspanho/aframe-hit-test